# unfortunately app has stopped while performing socket programming in android

Tags: android

MainActivity.java

```
    package com.example.vnc;

     import java.io.IOException;
     import java.io.PrintWriter;
     import java.net.Socket;
      import java.net.UnknownHostException;

      import android.app.Activity;
       import android.content.Intent;
      import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.Button;
      import android.widget.EditText;
   import android.widget.Toast;

      public class MainActivity extends Activity
       { 
    Button connect;
    EditText ipadd,portadd;
    Socket soc;
    String ip,port;
    int port1;
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    connect=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    connect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ipadd=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            portadd=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            ip=ipadd.getText().toString();
            port=portadd.getText().toString();
            port1=Integer.parseInt(port);

        new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
            try{
                soc=new Socket(ip,port1);
                PrintWriter out=new PrintWriter(soc.getOutputStream(),true);
                out.write("jaykapasi");
                out.close();
            }
            catch(UnknownHostException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Connecting to      Server"+ip,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent next1=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Password.class);
             startActivity(next1);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.vnc"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-            permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
       <application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.vnc.Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity> 

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.vnc.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.vnc.MainActivity" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity> 

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.vnc.Password"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.vnc.Password" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity> 

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.vnc.Security"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.vnc.Security" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity> 

     </application>
      </manifest>
```

This is my client side android code. My server is running on a PC. I am running jelly bean.
Please tell me what to do? Which ip address should I need to enter for connection? i.e from ipconfig or my dynamic ip?

Comment: Please post your logcat, thanks.

Comment: i have solved it but i have another doubt it is only connect when I am entering my ip address from ipconfig..it is not connecting when i am using dynamic ip address.

Comment: user3283519, if you have a router, check this: http://portforward.com/